# ajax POST: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-405

At the time of uploading image i am getting 405 (Method Not Allowd) error.
Below are the reference of HTML, JavaSceipt and php file code.
I am asking user to upload photo or to capture image using camera and sending it to server . As of now i have take php file

```
==================
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"> 
    <title>Clearestream Facial Recognition POC</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>Capture Image</div>
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="cameraInput" name="cameraInput">

<button type="submit" onclick="uploadImage()">Upload</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


======================
main.js
====================
var imageFile = document.getElementById("cameraInput").files[0];

function uploadImage() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.enctype="multipart/form-data";
    formData.append("fileToUpload", imageFile);

    $.ajax({
       url: "http://172.25.63.23:8080/upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
        alert("image uploaded");
           // .. do something
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
           alert("error in uploading image");
       }
    });
}
=================
upload.php
=================
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is page on same host and port as upload.php?

Comment: looks from header it isn't, try this more robust CORS implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers